# Worst grandmaster by rating

Tags: rating, fide, grandmaster

https://www.chess.com/forum/view/fun-with-chess/worlds-lowest-rated-grandmaster

This is a joke thread about the 'world's worst grandmaster', Panko Smoobachuk. Seeing this post, I wondered, what is the world's lowest rated grandmaster?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The new, munged* [FIDE rating website](https://ratings.fide.com/) still has the old "Advanced Search" option, but the page doesn't have its own URL. There you can search for GMs from all countries sorted by rating ascending and then you get that the Russian GM, [Vasily B Malinin](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/4140249), born in 1956 is the lowest rated GM with a standard rating of 2100.

Looking at his [individual calculations](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/4140249/calculations) shows that his rating has been in steady decline since 2004 which would suggest some life-changing event happened then, perhaps a health problem, which affected his chess playing ability.

*[mung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mung_(computer_term)) = self referential acronym = Mung Until No Good

**Update**: There are still a number of players in the 2100's but the Spanish GM [Mihai Suba](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/1203363/chart) is the new lowest rated GM on 1949 and still dropping. His [latest tournament](https://ratings.fide.com/calculations.phtml?id_number=1203363&period=2023-05-01&rating=0) results (April 2023) show that win, lose or draw and despite his decline he still loves playing chess.

He is a former [senior world champion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mihai_Suba) as recently as 2008  and author of *[Dynamic Chess Strategy](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Dynamic-Chess-Strategy-Modern-Classic/dp/9056916297)*, which was British Chess Federation Book of the Year in 1991.